# Visual Studio 2010 SP1 does not search for text in *.*

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I used to be able to search for a text in every file in solution, like that: http://vvcap.net/db/lWMPaSHxormUrFYlLo0Q.htp . After upgrading to VS2010 SP1, this doesn't work anymore:

```
Find all "description", Match case, Whole word, Subfolders, Keep modified files open, Find Results 1, "Entire Solution", "*.*"
  No files were found to look in.
  Find was stopped in progress.
```

What's interesting, I can still search if I know file extension, like this: http://vvcap.net/db/IFr8jCUa7J79sauBsNFC.htp :

```
Find all "description", Match case, Whole word, Subfolders, Keep modified files open, Find Results 1, "Entire Solution", "*.cs" 
... 
...   
Matching lines: 485    Matching files: 109    Total files searched: 970
```

Anyone knows wtf is going on here, and how to get around this?

Comment: Try the silverbullet - restart IDE! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what happened, but now my VS is searching for "*" again. Maybe after last windows update... I have no reasonable explanation as to wtf happened

Answer (score 0):

It's a known bug. You can get the [visual studio search results to appear](http://www.andrewdenhertog.com/tips/solved-visual-studio-no-search-results/) by using CTRL + Break in the Find Results window